# Ubuntu 18.04 - not using the full WiFi internet speed

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, iwlwifi

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on an `Asus VivoBook`. When using WiFi, I'm not able to have the full internet speed (250 Mb/s using windows).

```
wlo1  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"SFR_31B8_5GHZ"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.26 GHz  Access Point: 60:35:CC:1F:BB:BD   
      Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:17   Missed beacon:0
```

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Output of `dkms status`:

```
rtlwifi-new, 0.6: added
virtualbox, 5.2.34, 4.15.0-96-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Output of `grep iwlwifi /etc/modprobe.d/*`:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Output of `uname -r`

```
5.3.0-46-generic
```

I have already tried this

```
$ sudo iwconfig wlo1 rate 250M
```

Is there any fix to this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by `14.04` and `iwlwifi` tags? How do you measure speed?

Comment: I'm using online speed test. Sorry for the wrong tag version.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: I added the command output.

Comment: The kernel version is 4.15.0-96-generic.

Comment: Please also add output of `dkms status`.

Comment: What is the hw_mode in /etc/hostapd.conf. [See](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245402/236063)

Comment: @pLumo We've found the problem. It is `11n_disable` :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have disabled "partially" `11n` rates in your config files.

You replaced the standard `iwlwifi.conf` with a wrong option.

Run

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

and replace the existing text `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` with

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

This is what should be there.

For the future I recommend not to run commands that you don't understand.

Comment: I tried that. But, it didn't work.

Comment: Does `uname -a` show the 5.3 now?

Comment: And also add output of `grep iwlwifi /etc/modprobe.d/*` to your question. I see that you have some crap installed. Maybe you disabled normal rates yourself.

Comment: Yes, the kernel is updated to 5.3.0-46-generic .

Comment: So please add the above output and we'll see if there is anything that can be easily fixed.

Comment: So you broke it yourself. ;-) See the edit to the answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 They also have a dkms driver problem. See `dkms status`.

Comment: @heynnema I won't say it is a problem. There is some harmless crap. It is off-scope of this question ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 Don't you think that it would be appropriate to `dkms remove` the partially installed rtlwifi-new driver?

Comment: @heynnema I agree that it should be removed, but I see no harm in it. It is just added, so `dkms` won't process it at all.